# DetailViewController Dumb Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone app that has a `UITableView` with multiple entries and when you click on each, it takes you to the same view using a navigation controller.  This is good, I want the same view every time, except for one of my entries I want to hide a text label.  I have succeeded in doing this, except I did it in the `viewDidAppear` method, so when I push the view from the side, it shows up for just a split second before it disappears.  How do I fix this so that it never shows up?

Thanks,

VectorWare

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630649/what-is-the-difference-between-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear

Comment: Have you tried using viewWillAppear, instead?

Comment: did you try in viewWillAppear, or do it on ViewDidDisappear of your table view.

Comment: Yes, I have it didn't seem to work

Comment: i am talking about viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear of your table view controller

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet, I'll do it now

Comment: I tried and it still isn't working, for some reason my instance variables aren't passing right

Answer (score 2):

That requirement calls for the `viewWillAppear` method.

You can and **should** do all kinds of modifications to your view inside that method. 
All modifications will be applied to the objects in the current view before it gets shown via the `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` methods.

From the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> **viewWillAppear**: Notifies the view controller that its view is about to
>   be become visible.
>
> - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated Parameters animated If YES, the
>     view is being added to the window using an animation. Discussion This
>     method is called before the receiver’s view is about to be displayed
>     onscreen and before any animations are configured for showing the
>     view. You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated
>     with presenting the view. For example, you might use this method to
>     change the orientation or style of the status bar to coordinate with
>     the orientation or style of the view being presented. If you override
>     this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.
>
> For more information about the how views are added to windows, and the
>   sequence of messages that occur, see the information on presenting a
>   view controller’s view in “Custom View Controllers” in View Controller
>   Programming Guide for iOS

Comment: Got it.  I found the problem and it was resolved, thanks

Comment: How did you fix it and what was it?

Comment: For some reason my instance variables weren't passing right