# Reload root view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am working with a `UINavigationController` in my app.  In `viewDidLoad`, the root view controller acquires information from the internet, parses it, and displays it.

When going to another view in the `UINavigationController`, and then going back to the root `UIViewController`, the information in the controller is not reloaded.  This leads me to think that `viewDidLoad` is not being called.

What method should I use to ensure this information is reloaded when the root view controller is popped back to in the `UINavigationController`?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the quick responses guys, it means a lot.  One more question regarding your answers: `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`?  Are there pros/cons for each?

Comment: viewWillAppear will be processed right before the view is displayed, viewDidAppear will be processed after view is pushed on top of the stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should process `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`, depending on whether you'd like a reload to happen before or after thew view shows up on the screen. `viewDidLoad` is called only once, when the view is loaded.

Comment: Depending on when your information is retrieved and processed from the internet, you may also need to call `setNeedsDisplay` which will tell the device the view needs to be refreshed.

Comment: @DevinGund Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5659007/335858) to an excellent answer to your follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidLoad` is only called after the view is loaded the first time.

Check about this here:

[UIView Programattion Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

Answer (score 1):

And you are right, it's not being called. If you want to call it everytime you go to that `UIViewController` (you have one inside your `UINavigationController`) just put it on the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

---

`viewWillAppear` happens before `viewDidAppear`. For speed purposes, I would do it on the `viewDidAppear` on a secondary thread in a async way, so the UI thread wouldn't slow down. Once the data was retrieved, I would update the view.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when the View Controller is initially created, or if it was unloaded because it was hidden and the application received a memory warning. You can alternately implement `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` to refresh your UI.