# Navbar not changing background immediately - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, navbar

I'm trying to change my navbar's background with the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_bg_smooth.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [super viewDidLoad];
...

}
```

It works, but the problem I'm having is that the change first takes effect when you go BACK the the view where this code is located. So it you go to this view the navbar is not changed but if you go further and then go back to this view the changes take effect.

Does anyone have any clue what the issue might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: keep this line  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_bg_smooth.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; in appdelgate didfinishlaunching method and see how it is coming....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_bg_smooth.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
...

}
```

Comment: this maybe correct. Why maybe? It is because `self.navigationController.navigationBar` does not necessarily have values in it. It may be `nil` and if so, your code will crash.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala This worked Thank you so much! Take in to consideration what Shivan Raptor wrote adn make sure that the navbar is there

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` only fired once when the view is loaded. To run the code every time when you see the view, put the codes in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` (depends on your usage)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659007/188331) helps you choose from `viewDidLoad` , `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, but switching to viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear did not do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` method: and write this method in `viewWillAppear`

```
[navbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] 
               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

this will help you a lot....

Comment: `navbar`? where did the variable come from?

Comment: navbar is a variable of `self.navigationController.navigationBar`

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
UIView *backgroundView = ...
[navigationBar insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Also see this link....[setting-custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-what-will-work-on-ios5-and-ios4-too](http://www.mladjanantic.com/setting-custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-what-will-work-on-ios5-and-ios4-too/)