# ViewDidAppear more faster

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, viewdidappear

I have a UItextview where I can write inside and with a Data Class I can give the data anywhere in my Views, In the ViewDidAppear function I pass my data but It is a little bit slow. The text appear after 0.2-0.3 second, How I can solve that problem?!

Comment: write your code in did load section

Comment: thats what view did appear does! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630649/what-is-the-difference-between-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some diagnostics offline, we concluded that the delay in question was really just the standard delay as you switch from one tab to another, and was nothing exceptional. This delay was exacerbated because we were observing the UX via the simulator rather than a real device. So, a couple of conclusions:

1. Alway perform benchmarking using actual device rather than simulator.
2. Rather than reacting to perceived delays, always quantify the effect, for example:

   ```
   let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

   // do some stuff

   let elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
   println(String(format: "%@ took %.2f seconds", __FUNCTION__, elapsed))
   ```
3. Sometimes, using the Time Profiler tool in Instruments (using the "Record Waiting Threads" option) can be useful in tracking down these issues. For practical demonstration of this, see WWDC 2012 video [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211).

Answer (score 1):

Do it in `viewDidLoad:` method.

See UIViewController lifecycle :

[image]

Comment: I do not think this will account for the 0.2-0.3 second delay. By the way, that diagram is outdated, as `viewDidUnload` isn't called any more.