# Should I put values in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have VC that links to another VC containing a tableView.

Then form the table view I exit back to the root VC where I also display the items selected in the table VC.

But should I load those items in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: Do you want to execute the code before the view appears or after?  Generally it is cleaner to set everything up before the view appears

Comment: recommended read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630649/what-is-the-difference-between-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `viewWillAppear` for your dynamic code like changes of the tableview-data etc. You can use `viewDidAppear` for things that should only happen, if the view is already on screen.