# When is viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear actually called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I always thought that `viewDidAppear` was called whenever your view appeared on the screen, but I've been told that, for example, when you background an app (by pressing home button) and then bring it back up, `viewDidAppear` is not called (going to background "doesn't remove the current view from the view hierarchy"). So, what does it actually mean for a view to "appear"? Also, what does it mean for a view to "load", ie. when does it actually happen (for example, when the app is opened by touching the app icon, etc.)

Comment: An easy way to get a better understanding is to add nslog statements in a view controller and take a look at the output.

Comment: Just go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630649/what-is-the-difference-between-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear

Answer (score 16):

**Is Heirarchy Of this:-** Alwys Whenevr Your View Controller Runs It Go Like This

1st ViewDidLoad

2nd ViewAppear

3rd ViewDidAppear

4th ViewWillDisAppear

5th ViewDidDisAppear

Last 6th ViewDidUnload

**You Can Understand This by This Simple Life Example :-**

Suppose You Are In **Cafe** And

**1st**==> You Ordered **Coffee** Then Service Here Your **Call** Then They **Fill** Your Coffee On The **Cup** (**Note** Loading Or Filling All Contain Like Coffee on Cup Is Called **ViewDidLoad** )

**2nd**==>> And When Service Put **Coffee** On Your Table (**Note** Is Called **ViewWillAppear** Where Your Coffee just Like Your ViewController **View** )

**3rd**==>> And When You See Your **Coffe** (**Note** Is Called **ViewDidAppear** Where Your View Can See On Your Screen Just Like When Your See Your Coffee )

**4th**==>> After That When You **Finished** Your **Macachino Coffee** And is Empty (**Note** is Called **ViewWillDisAppear** Where Unloading or Proccess Of Empty is Stands For ViewWillDisAppear )

**5th & 6th**==>> And After That When Service Came And It's Pick Up Your Coffee **Cup** And Take Back From You  When Is Did Disappear From Your Eyes (**Note** is Called **ViewDidDisAppear** When View or Your Screen Is Go Blank Just Like Your Cup )  And Finally All Proccesss Done Here....

**And If** You Again ordered Diff. Coffee Aur Same Coffee That All Step Called Again Same Like That, You Have Multiple ViewController And They Call Again Again A--B--A--B

Thx For Listing This Story Happy Coding

Comment: TL;DR - cool analogy tho ;)

Comment: Really like the answer

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` is called when all outlets are initialized from a Storyboard.

`viewDidAppear` calls when a View Controller is added to another view controller hierarchy. Usually after all animations is finished, but not necessary.

If you implement custom controller which will contain some child view controllers, you will call `didMoveToParentViewController` of the child controllers when they are added to the parent. So, whenever you call this method `viewDidAppear` of child VC's will be called automatically.

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` is called after your view is loaded. It is called only once when view is initialized and pushed or presented.

`viewDidAppear` is called once you see the loaded view on screen. It is called after view appeared.
`ViewDidAppear` is called everytime when you see the view after it is loaded. if you push and then pop any other viewController on that view then again `viewDidAppear` gets called.

Lifecycle of view Controller:

1. ViewDidLoad
2. ViewWillAppear
3. ViewDidAppear

Comment: Not entirely true. viewWillAppear is not called when a popover modal ViewController above the current ViewController is popped.