# UIImage is getting nil from the UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to update an image on the `Viewcontroller`, I am using `ImagePickerController` and I could able to see `chosenImage` has data, and I assign it. When image is chosen and then this `viewcontroller` is loading again, I could able to debug to see whether or not it hits `loadUserProfile` method, yes it is. But `UIImage` is getting nil in somewhere and somehow.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *userPicImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *userProfileImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadUserProfile];
}

-(void)loadUserProfile
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * userImageURL = [defaults objectForKey:@"imageURL"];    
    bool isReload = [defaults boolForKey:@"isReload"];

    if(isReload)
    {
         //self.userPicImage is always nil
         [self.userProfileImage setImage:self.userPicImage];
         [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"comingBack"];
         [defaults synchronize];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType source = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   // userPicImage is not nil here!
    self.userPicImage = chosenImage;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"isReload"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{        
        if (source == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hm, did you check the `self` in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and `loadUserProfile` is the same address or not?

Comment: check with this post and do the modification of the code based on your requirement. http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-image-picker-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Whenever `viewdidload` is called the `viewcontroller` is loaded as a new one [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640493/when-is-viewdidload-viewdidappear-actually-called), all of its reference outlets and variables are set to new. In your case `userPicImage` is initiated as new object so logically there wont be any content in it.
- You better store your image data in `userdefaults` and retrieve it from there.

Comment: very helpful 

Answer (score 1):

try this code because when you load again vc than image data is nil so first convert image data to base64string .

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *userPicImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *userProfileImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadUserProfile];
}

-(void)loadUserProfile
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * userImageURL = [defaults objectForKey:@"imageURL"];
    bool isReload = [defaults boolForKey:@"isReload"];

    if(isReload)
    {
        //self.userPicImage is always nil
        NSString *base64String=[defaults stringForKey:@"chosenimage"];
        NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        self.userProfileImage.image=image;
      //  [self.userProfileImage setImage:self.userPicImage];
        [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"comingBack"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType source = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    // userPicImage is not nil here!
    self.userPicImage = chosenImage;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0);
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:encodedString forKey:@"chosenimage"];
    [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"isReload"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        if (source == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        }
    }];
}
```