# How do I load view THEN load data in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wondering if you could help me with loading data after the view has loaded. I am using a URL to load data into my label, though, over time you open the page it needs to download the information before displaying the view. Is there a way to display the view as the information is being downloaded, and the information appear when ready?

The code I am currently using is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL *urlTitle = [NSURL URLWithString:@" URL GOES HERE "];
    NSString *TitleLabel = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlTitle encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
    TermTitleLabel.text = TitleLabel;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: try using the code in - (void)viewDidAppear{ }

Comment: Some not question related feedback: Variables in obj-c and swift are usually typed in camel-case, like `titleLabel` without the first character capitalized. Class names are capitalized, but variables and outlets are not.

Comment: @OscarApeland Thanks, just learning, so feedback on making my coding neater is appreciated!

Comment: I assumed! Check out [this guide for obj-c](https://github.com/raywenderlich/objective-c-style-guide) or [this for swift](https://github.com/bakkenbaeck/iOS-playbook/blob/master/SWIFT_STYLE_GUIDE.md) if you'd like to learn more about how you ideally should write your code. A lot of it is really nit-picky, so don't think too much about it, but its a good read to have in the back of your head! :)

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the view in the `viewDidLoad` method along with a loading animation or "Loading..." message. This would ensure that the label and the loading message / animation appear together.

Use `NSURLSession`'s `dataTaskWithRequest` to download your data from the URL.
You can do this in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods. `viewDidAppear` would be a better choice if the quantity of data to be downloaded is huge.

The `dataTaskWithRequest`'s completion handler can be used to load the data into your label and to remove the loading message / animation.

You can check this blog post on where you can layout / load views: http://kevindew.me/post/18579273258/where-to-progmatically-lay-out-views-in-ios-5-and

Check this Stack Overflow post to find out the difference between viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear: [What is the difference between -viewWillAppear: and -viewDidAppear:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630649/what-is-the-difference-between-viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear)