# Strange behaviour when hiding Navigation Bar Back Button

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've created my Storyboard with a LoginViewController which is set as the RootViewController. If the user is already logged then I just segue to the HomeViewController.

The problem is on the HomeViewController. I don't want the user to navigate back to the LoginViewController so I'm trying to hide the back button in the HomeViewController using:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, false);
}
```

Doing this hides the button on the HomeViewController as expected, however when I navigate to any other VC's the Back button is still hidden but tappable because I can tap where the button would be and it would navigate back to the HomeVC. If I then navigate again to the same VC as before, the Back button is visible. So basically it's only hidden on the first load.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you set SetHidesBackButton in your ViewWillAppear.
Copy paste it in your ViewDidLoad(), and it should work just fine.

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659007/4375106)

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem with `rootViewController` which you assign and also with `navigationController`. To avoid this behaviour you should Navigate and assign `rootViewController` from AppDelegate, also, improve your back button hiding code.

*For more help please paste code, Thank You!*

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

     var rootView: MyRootViewController = MyRootViewController()

     if let window = self.window{
            window.rootViewController = rootView
     }

     return true
}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: What's the difference between setting the RootViewController in AppDelegate instead of Storyboard? Also you don't really explain what the problem is with my RootViewController/ NavigationController - can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: @empo Yes you can use it from anywhere  but, I didn't seen the code so just a suggestion and good way if we could define rootViewController from AppDelegate. Also hiding back button you should use from viewDidLoad. Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to hide the button. Use NavigationController as root. Push login then home and remove login from navigation stack.