# viewDidLoad not running when expected

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nslog, viewdidload

I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad` to change an image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"colour"] == nil) {
        [defaults setObject:@"Red" forKey:@"colour"];
        [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"colourIndex"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }


    [background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]);
    // Logs "Blue"
}
```

When I open my flipside view in the iPhone Simulator and then go back to my original view, the result of the `NSLog` doesn't change and the image doesn't change. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this code to viewWillAppear.  viewDidLoad is not called every time the view is presented.

This link provides a good explanation.

[UIViewController viewDidLoad vs. viewWillAppear: What is the proper division of labor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579550/uiviewcontroller-viewdidload-vs-viewwillappear-what-is-the-proper-division-of)