# May I use viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad for most of my initialization and setup?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear

I'm not good in communicating between controllers, so i need to setup and check a lot from NSUserDefaults, may it cause any problems?

Comment: Running a long process in viewDidLoad will make the app unresponsive for a period of time. If this happens between table views, your app will stall with the table cell highlighted, causing a lot of frustration for your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to do after the form start-to-finish of loading the view.

You don't want to do too much in `viewWillAppear` (Called when the view is ready to be shown) as it could impact performance; typically you want to do things like refresh a table, or update the text on a label etc. The `viewDidLoad` method is called once the view is loaded and it is common to add things like buttons, labels etc, anything that you want to appear on the view. If you have anything tasks that may take long to execute, it is better to do them in the `viewDidAppear` as the view has already been loaded; it is good practice to perform these methods on a separate thread, or at least provide the user with some sort of activity indicator until the work is done.

Comment: This helped me to solve the viewDidLayoutSubviews infinite loop bug. Thanks. I just put my minimal setup code in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Do remember `viewDidLoad` is called once after the view is loaded. 
But `viewWillAppear` is called when ever your view becomes visible. With this information you can decide to place.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579624/641062) for more info.