# How to change the background color of a UITableView in the correct way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use code to generate UI instead of IB. I've tried setting the `backgroundView` to `nil` in the initialization of the table view, and changing the `backgroundColor` directly in the `viewDidLoad`, but both failed in changing the background color of the table view.

Finally, I set the `backgroundColor` in the `viewWillAppear`, and it works!

So, what happened between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` on the table view? Why its background color is changed in this phrase?

Here's my code:

```
// in tableview's init, doesn't work
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundView = nil;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    return self;
}

// loadView
- (void)loadView {
    _personalView = [NSBPersonalView new];
    self.tableView = _personalView;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}


// in view controller's viewDidLoad, doesn't work either
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}

// but in view controller's viewWillAppear, it works
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579550/uiviewcontroller-viewdidload-vs-viewwillappear-what-is-the-proper-division-of       may this help to clear ur confusion .....!!!

Comment: I just wonder why the properties of a tableview will be changed after `viewDidLoad` even there are set in the `init`.

Comment: can u show me the code, what u exactly have written?

Comment: You forgot to call `[super viewDidLoad];`. Probably not whats wrong but just saying... :)

Comment: It should work in viewDidLoad. Where do you initialize the tableView?

Comment: I init the tableView in the `loadView` in the view controller.

Comment: yes, i forgot to call `[super viewDidLoad]`, but it still doesn't work after i add the super call.

Comment: To set the backgroundColor of a UITableView, you first need to remove the backgroundView property of UITableView

Comment: Setting a tableView's background color in viewDidLoad works just fine. Please post actual code, and post more of it, including loadView and your custom tableview class (there's hardly any reason to subclass it anyway).

Comment: I've tried both setting the `backgroundView` to nil and setting the `backgroundView` to a new UIView,  but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not calling `super loadView`, `super viewDidLoad`. And you're not assigning `self.view` in `loadView`

Comment: Should it be not calling `[super loadView]` when use code to form the view rather than IB???

Comment: @vulgur The view property is supposed to be initialized in loadView, you aren't doing that either.

Comment: But I do the initialization in the `init` of the tableView, and it is called in the `loadView`, this is not right way?