# If not in viewDidLoad, where should I make initial network calls (say, to initially populate a feed)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, state-restoration

Previously I made my initial network calls to populate the user's feed in `viewDidLoad`, right after all the views were set up.

However, with iOS' state restoration mechanism, this doesn't work as the state restoration is performed *after* `viewDidLoad`, so if I want to prevent the call from being made as data is already populated from the restoration, I can't, because that's only known after `viewDidLoad`.

So where should I do initial network calls and the like? `viewDidAppear` seems wrong as every time you navigate back from the navigation controller stack that gets called. I could set a flag that the initial call has already been made, but that seems a little gross.

Typical advice seems to be to do the one time things [in viewDidLoad, not viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579624/998117), which is why I'm apprehensive.

Is there a suggested strategy here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set flag in the UIApplicationDelegate's delegate method,then use in the Controller's viewDidLoad?