# advice - Bottom navigation handling

Tags: ios, tabbar

I am new in iOS and I have tab bar. I have 4 tabs like Facebook.

In my case all data should be updated from server anytime when user goes one of that screen.

One guy said calling `viewDidLoad` frequently can make memory leaks. Is that true?

So what's the best play here? Every time call `viewDidLoad()` and load data from server or there is another way to handle this not calling `viewDidLoad()` every time.

There is no pull to refresh in that screens

[image]

Comment: viewDidAppear()?

Comment: @pmb here is the answer-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579550/uiviewcontroller-viewdidload-vs-viewwillappear-what-is-the-proper-division-of. Not sure about memory leak though I don't think so.Or even I would like to now other members suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad()` will only be called the first time the view controller is loaded. Using a tab bar controller will usually keep the view controllers in memory as the user switches tabs so if you want the loading to occur every time the user goes to a new screen, this is not the best place for it.

I would suggest using `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. If you're updating data from the network, make sure to do the loading on a background thread to ensure the interface does not get blocked (regardless of which method you use).

Personally I would put network loading code inside `viewDidAppear` as to me it makes more sense to call the network after the view has finished appearing since it will presumably not finish immediately. This way it is also easier to present a UI element that shows data is loading to the user.